# How do I populate a spinner with an array I created in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a `Spinner` that is populated with data from an `Array` I created in Java that reads from a text file.

```
Spinner spinner;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pokemon.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    String[] array = (String[]) lines.toArray();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    Typeface Dotum = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/gulim.ttc");
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.jingenMenu1);
    myTextView.setTypeface(Dotum);

    spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pkmnSel1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,    , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); //I know it's missing the source but, that's where I'm
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);                                                                             //lost because I can't figure out how to populate it with my array.
}
```

Comment: Android is different than Java. There's no `main()` entry point. You need to call that code somewhere else like `onCreate()` then you can load your spinner after the array has been populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `main()` function in Android like @codeMagic mentioned above. `onCreate()` is the function that runs when application is created. You could create a new function that returns Array for Spinner and call it in your `onCreate()` something like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    Typeface Dotum = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/gulim.ttc");
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.jingenMenu1);
    myTextView.setTypeface(Dotum);

    String[] array = yourFunctionThatReturnsArray();

    spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pkmnSel1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,array    , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); //I know it's missing the source but, that's where I'm
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);                                                                             //lost because I can't figure out how to populate it with my array.
} 

public String[] yourFunctionThatReturnsArray(){
       String[] array = new String[SIZE];
       // put anything in array
       return array;
}
```